# Transfer Twilio voice Autobot to a telephone number

Tags: twilio

I'm a Twilio newbie so please be gentle.

I'm creating an Autopilot bot to be used via Alexa that in in some circumstances needs to transfer the voice to a telephone number. I'm using my mobile as the destination for testing. I have written a Function to transfer the call which then calls my mobile. All good so far, but as soon as the call is made the Twilio session ends - the call is received and I hear on my mobile "I'm sorry an application error has occurred". I'm guessing I'm missing parameter to connect the voice session to the call. Where have I gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Task:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "say": "Connecting you"
        },
        {
            "handoff": {
                "method": "POST",
                "channel": "voice",
                "uri": "https://qwerty.twil.io/call-me"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Function code:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  // Get an initialized Twilio API client
  const client = context.getTwilioClient();

  // Make a new phone call, using our first function
  // to provide the TwiML for the call
  client.calls.create({
    url: 'https://' + context.DOMAIN_NAME + '/voice',
        to: '+44MyMobileNumber', 
        from: '+44MyTwilioNumber'
  }, function(err, result) {
    console.log('New phone call started...');
    console.log(result);

    // End our function
    callback();
  });
};
```

Comment: Hi Wyn, are you expecting the person on the Alexa side to speak to the person being called (not possible) or are you calling the person on the Alexa side using their mobile phone number, and then plan on connecting them to an agent lets say? 

When you make an outbound-api call to set-up the call, you need to provide Twilio either TwiML or a URL containing TwiML which will execute once the dialed party answers the call, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls-node-js.

Comment: @Alan. It should be possible as Twilio support 'handoff' to their flex product and/or a telephone number.

Comment: Even if I use the Twilio simulator (no alexa involved) it does work.

Comment: The Flex handoff is always using the same media type (so SMS to Flex agent via SMS, where Autopilot engagement was initially SMS). There isn't a capability to go from one media type, Alexa, to another Voice, unless you explicitly call back the Alexa user. For the Twilio Simulator, are you using Voice?

Comment: Hi, yes I'm using the voice simulator.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to Handoff the call in Autopilot to a Twiml Bin that makes the call.